# I there a way to prevent a specific program or any program from disabling the Windows-key?

Tags: windows

A game I play received an update, after which it seems that when the game is running, it is preventing my Windows-key from functioning (opening the start-menu).

My Windows-key is not working at all when the game is open, even if the game is minimized or not the active window.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this specific program or all/any program for that matter from hijacking my Windows-key behaviour?

This new behaviour was such a surprise that I didn't pinpoint it to be the game's fault at first, so I tried:

- Running this command in elevated Powershell: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
- Disabling filter keys (they were already disabled)
- Disabling game mode (it was already disabled)
- Checking that my keyboard doesn't have a dip-switch or equivalent which prevents the Windows-key from working

The reason why I am certain that it is the game's doing is that the Windows-key gets consistently disabled every time the game is open and starts working again when the game is closed.

Comment: I use many, many Apps.  You need to contact the game Support center.

Comment: @John I don't want to. I am looking for a more general solution, of which I am in control of, should the same issue arise again with some other program in the future.

Comment: The best type of questions are highly focused looking for specific answers instead of asking for general solutions

Comment: is there a windowed (perhaps border-less full-screen) mode for the game? lots of games have a history of bugs that occur when the game loses and then subsequently regains focus. eating win-key presses is not a remediation Ive seen before, but I can certainly conceive of why some engineer thought "the best way to fix this entirely is to make the stupid user not do things the program doesn't like". in the long run you will have the best experience if you name the software in question, and perhaps SU isn't the perfect venue for this question.

Comment: @FrankThomas This is a game packed with Electron and I suppose it uses Electron's methods to bind the keys. I happen to have a broad web development background and the key in question being the WinKey specifically, I think that the binding of that specific key is done by having Electron to set a global shortcut/hotkey in Windows, as there are not many other convenient ways to do it in this context. The key not working even if the game is minimized or not active would also support this global hotkey theory. As for you question, AFAIK the game can be only run in windowed mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have pseudo-fixed the issue with a simple AutoHotkey-script:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

LWin:: {
    DllCall("DefWindowProc", "ptr", A_ScriptHwnd, "uint", 0x112, "ptr", 0xF130, "ptr", 0)
}

RWin:: {
    DllCall("DefWindowProc", "ptr", A_ScriptHwnd, "uint", 0x112, "ptr", 0xF130, "ptr", 0)
}
```

The script takes advantage of AutoHotkey's [override-functionality](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Override.htm) of even global hotkeys and rebinds both the left and right windows keys to perform a direct `DllCall` to open up the start-menu instead.

Note that this is just a "quick and dirty" implementation and it currently works like so that `Win+E` and other hotkeys do not work, as any Windows-key press will immediately bring up the start-menu. Developing it further to fix these issues should be fairly trivial though, but I am only interested in having my Windows-key -> Start Menu functionality back.

Another problem with this implementation is that I am using [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu), which replaces the (horrible) native Start Menu with an older one. This AutoHotkey-script will open the native Start Menu instead of the Open-Shell one, for which I don't have a solution yet.

This AutoHotkey-script however, should work in all cases where some program decides to disable the Windows-key functionality. It can even be targeted to only override the Windows-key when the program disabling it is active, should someone want it to work that way.

Also note that for this script to work with some applications, especially some of those which are fullscreen or borderless, [you might have to run the script with administrator permissions](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=20655#:%7E:text=You%20may%20need%20to%20run,so%20AHK%20needs%20the%20same.).